# Call graphql query in fetch method

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have to call graphql query in the fetch method. So how can I call this method?

I have to call the below query in the fetch method.

```
query AddressList($street:String, $city:String, $state:String, $zip:String) {
   address_list(street:$street, city:$city, state:$state, zip:$zip){
    street
    city
    state
    zip
    
  }
}
```

Anyone, please suggest me a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: suggestion: use search

Answer (score 1):

[I](http://tnickel.de/) am using this one:

```js
    async function graphql(query, variables={}){
        const r = await fetch('/graphql', {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                query,
                variables
            })
        });
        var result = (await r.json());

        // error handling
        if(result.errors){
            throw result.errors
            
        }
        
        if(r.ok){
            return result.data
        }
        
        throw result;
    }
```

You can use it like:

```js
const { address_list } = await graphql(`query AddressList($street:String, $city:String, $state:String, $zip:String) {
   address_list(street:$street, city:$city, state:$state, zip:$zip){
    street
    city
    state
    zip
    
  }
}`,{street:'streetName',city: 'cityName', state:'stateName'})
```